# React Native & Jest: How to properly test a component that calls fetch in useEffect. "Can't access .root on unmounted test renderer"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, fetch-mock

I want to test my component in Jest and that it is displaying fetched data correctly. I have the following component, which has a `useEffect` hook that calls a function called `getData`. `getData` fetches to the back end API, converts the response to `json`, and returns the `json` to the component. The data is then updated in state and displayed on screen. The returned data is a very simple array that looks like: `[{ title: "test", id: 1 }, ...]`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { getData } from "./getData"; // <- returns an array

const MyComponent = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      const returnedArray = await getData(); // <- returns an array
      setData(returnedArray);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={ data }
        renderItem={item => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

I want to run the following test, trying to mock the fetch call within `global.fetch`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render, act } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
  title: "test",
  id: 1
}));

describe('Testing react native', () => {
  it('displays data from useEffect hook', async () => {

    const { getByText } = await act(async () => render(<MyComponent />));

    const title = getByText("test");

    expect(title).toBeTruthy();
  });
}
```

This test is failing with the following error:

```
Can't access .root on unmounted test renderer
```

Can someone help me understand the proper way to test a Component that fetches data from a `useEffect` hook in `Jest`? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? Having the same issues... testing with "react-testing-library" that is supposed to make things "easier" is anything but...

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. Have you found a solution to this?